# Consume Service Through Spring boot (content Type=multipart/form-data; boundary="====errr123==")'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to consume service (content type = multipart/form-data; boundary="====out234=="') with request body contains 'Text'

### body of request-

```
`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="request";
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <keyList>
        <listItem>
            <entryUri>44243513564125</entryUri>
        </listItem>
        <listItem>
            <entryUri>test:44243513564125@msg.tc.test.com</entryUri>
        </listItem>
    </keyList>`

`44243513564125` value will be set dynamically in below XML` tag `
`<entryUri>test:44243513564125@msg.tc.test.com</entryUri>`
`<entryUri>44243513564125</entryUri>`
```

**So how to consume service in spring boot with restTemplate?**